# lintian and script-not-executable

Tags: debian

I'm trying to make a `deb` package. But there is warning from lintian:

```
W: package: script-not-executable etc/package/hooks/script
```

It is a script, but noone executes it directly. I source it in another script.
Do I need to make it executable to pass lintian, or remove its shebang header?

Comment: What is the script in question? The simplest thing is to make it executable. Lintian is probably issuing this warning based on the script category. What do you have it categorized as?

Comment: What do you mean "script category"? I just wrote in debian/install `etc/hooks etc/program/hooks`, so my script from etc/hooks will be copied in /etc/program/hooks. Is it right way?

Comment: Sorry, I was being vague. I meant for example that if the script was a preinst or postinst script, then it would be expected to be executable, for example. It is also possible that lintian is checking for shebang headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it's giving you this error because it's not marked as executable, but you have the header line that indicates it should be executed through whichever interpreter.  If it is only ever going to be sourced and has no use being executed on its own, you should remove the shebang line (perhaps add a comment describing how the file is used / where it's sourced from).  Otherwise, do set the executable bit.